# Will jQuery close a TCP connection after Ajax request is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tcp

I have a jQuery script the runs every second using `setInterval()`. This script makes an ajax request to a php script "i.e. handler.php"

My jQuery code looks like this

```
    function checkMessages(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'handler.php',     
            data: {method: 'getMessages', jSON: true},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 1000,
            success: function(data) {
                if(requestCounter <= 1){

                    if(requestCounter < 3){
                        requestCounter++;
                    }

                }

                processServerData(data);
            }
        });
    }



    function startCalls(){

            setInterval(function() {
                                checkMessages();
                            }, 1000);
    }
```

After the ajax finishes, will jQuery automatically close the TCP connection to the server or I must close it manually?

Comment: This isn't something jQuery does; it's a matter of how browsers implement XHR. And no, there's no API to close a connection for XHR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will jQuery automatically close the TCP connection to the server or I must close it manually?

The simple answer is: You should not care.

jQuery operates on an abstraction level<sup>(*)</sup> where you neither can initiate TCP connections manually nor tear them down manually, even if you wanted to. Everything is taken care of by the browser.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> *Everything* you can do from within JavaScript in the browser operates on that abstraction level. Not only for convenience, but also for security.

- In a scripting platform that concentrates on UI generation, things like manually managing TCP connections are entirely out of scope. Abstracting these things away is more than sensible.
- You do not want random web pages access your low level system resources with a few lines of script, so browsers a constructed in such a way that they can't.
- You can tell the browser whether to keep open connections or close them immediately via [the `Connection` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10). Try adding `Connection: close` to your response.

Comment: To detail the level of abstraction; it's entirely possible your XHR request won't ever even open a TCP connection, because the resource was instructed to cache on the browser for a certain time.

Comment: @Katana314 Exactly. And as a user (i.e. as a web developer) you have little way of knowing which is which.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am trying to solve for a problem where a server is reaching a max TCP connection allowed "i.e. 5000." Although I can increase the limit but I need to understand why would the server reach that many. My thoughts are that the TCP connection does not close which is causing the TCP connection to peak causing the limit to be reached.

Comment: Have you looked at the number of TCP connections a client window keeps open during the lifetime of your page? Does it increase?

Comment: I'd also mention that http requests (jQuery) are not the only type of TCP requests, so if your server is more than just a web server, there may be other sources of connections.

Comment: I agree with Erik, the issue is too broad to be successfully debugged here. You need to narrow down the problem first.

Comment: @Tomalak How can I tell if the TCP connection in increasing for the web browser? so my handler.php file should also returns `Connection: close` in the header every time it is requested?

Comment: After you've made sure that that's the actual cause. Don't apply any remedy without a proper diagnosis. There are diagnostic tools that show you the connections per process. Windows has the very convenient TCPView and Process Explorer, Linux has netstat and a couple of others, I'm sure. First work on the server to get an idea where the connections come from and where they end, then work on the client to figure out who is causing them and if there's a correlation with your code.